# HoloLens/Unity shared experience: How to track a user's "world" position instead of Unity's position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, multiplayer, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I have here an AR game I'm developing for the HoloLens that involves rendering holograms according the the users's relative position. It's a multiplayer shared experience where everyone in the same physical room connects to the same instance (shared Unity scene) hosted via cloud or LAN, and the players who have joined can see holograms rendering at other player's positions.

For example: Player A, and B join an instance, they're in the same room together. Player A can see a hologram above Player B tracking Player B's position (A Sims cursor if you will). Then once Player A gets closer to Player B, a couple more holographic panels can open up displaying the stats of Player B. These panels are also tracking Player B's position and are always rendered with a slight offset relative to Player B's headset position. Player B also sees the same on Player A and vice versa.

That's fundamentally what my AR game does for the time being.

**Problem:

The problem I'm trying to solve is tracking the user's position absolutely to the room itself instead of using the coordinate positions Unity says Player A's game object is at and Player B's.**

My app works beautifully if I mark a physical position on the floor and a facing direction that all the players must assume when starting the Unity app. This then forces the coordinate system in all the player's Unity app to have a matching origin point and initial heading in the real world. Only then am I able to render holograms relative to a User's position and have it correlate 1:1 between the Unity space and real physical space around the headset.

But what if I want Player A to start the app on one side of the room and have Player B start the app on the other side of the room? When I do this, the origin point of Player A's Unity world is at different physical spot than Player B. Then this would result in Holograms rendering A's position or B's position at a tremendous offset.

I have some screenshots showing what I mean.

In this one, I have 3 HoloLenses. The two on the floor, plus the one I'm wearing to take screenshots.
There's a blue X on the floor (It's the sheet of paper. I realized you can't see it in the image.) where I started my Unity app on all three HoloLenses. So the origin of the Unity world for all three is that specific physical location. As you can see, the blue cursor showing connected players works to track the headset's location beautifully. You can even see the headsets's location relative to the screenshooter on the minimap.

The gimmick here to make the hologram tracking be accurate is that all three started in the same spot.
[image]

Now in this one, I introduced a red X. I restarted the Unity app on one of the headsets and used the red X as it's starting spot. As you can see in this screenshot, the tracking is still precise, but it comes at a tremendous offset. Because my relative origin point in Unity (the blue X) is different than the others headset's relative origin point (the red X).
[image]

**Problem:

So this here is the problem I'm trying to solve. I don't want all my users to have to initialize the app in the same physical spot one after the other to make the holograms appear in the user's correct position. The HoloLens does a scan of the whole room right?
Is there not a way to synchronize these maps together with all the connected HoloLenses then they can share what their absolute coordinates are? Then I can use those as a transform point in the Unity scene instead of having to track multiplayer game objects**.

Here's a map on my headset I used the get the screenshots from the same angel
[image]

Comment: You will need a common real world reference (e.g. QR Tracking, Vuforia, etc) and then use it as the shared World origin (-> place an object on the tracker and spawn everything below => relative to it). There was also some experimental thing for sharing WorldAnchor references relative to a common room mesh ... don't know what became of it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was deleted because reasons, so round #2. Something about link-only answers.

So, here's the link again.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-05

And to avoid the last situation, I'm going to add that whomever wants a synchronized multiplayer experience with HoloLens should read through the whole tutorial series. I am not providing a summary on how to do this wihtout having to copy and paste the docs. Just know that you need a spatial anchor that others load into their scene.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky with inside-out tracking as everything is relative to the observer (as you've discovered).  What you need is to be able to identify a common, *unique* real-location that your system will then treat as 'common origin'.  Either a QR code or unique object that the system can detect and localise should suffice, then keep track of your user's (and other tracked objects) offset from that known origin within the virtual world.

Comment: Sounds like using QR codes might be a viable work around. Maybe I could make use of Vuforia and use a marker as the defining origin. Maybe that could work. I'm worried that the position at which a game object would spawn from the marker will be different in Player's A coordinate space vs Player B. I will need to look into this.

Comment: @GhostRavenstorm you would either always need to recalculate the positions/movements etc relative to the tracker transform or simply spawn everything below it ;)